# Laravel Eloquent hasMany returning only one result?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

So my `Client` model has a `hasMany` relationship with the `Project` model, because every client in the `client` table is associated with many projects in the `projects` table.

The method looks like this:

Client.php:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Projects', 'id', 'project_id');
}
```

Seems pretty straightforward.  But when I try this from a controller:

```
$projects = Client::find(1)->projects()->get()
```

I get only a single result, the FIRST result, from the Project model, when there should be about a half dozen.
This even happens if I change the integer sent to find().

So Eloquent is returning on the first row of the projects table every time.  Why is it doing this and/or how can I get all of the relevant results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `hasMany` (or `one-to-many`) relationship is defined in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) as

> A "one-to-many" relationship is used to define relationships where a single model owns any amount of other models.

In this case `Many` simply means one or more.

---

I assume that every project has a `client_id` reference. In that case changing your `projects()` function to

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Projects', 'client_id');
```

should work for you.

Comment: So how would I return all matching results from a single model?